# Derivative of sigmoid function $\sigma (x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In my AI textbook there is this paragraph, without any explanation.

> The sigmoid function is defined as follows
>
> $$\sigma (x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}.$$
>
> This function is easy to differentiate because
>
> $$\frac{d\sigma (x)}{d(x)} = \sigma (x)\cdot (1-\sigma(x)).$$

It has been a long time since I've taken differential equations, so could anyone tell me how they got from the first equation to the second?

Comment: What AI textbook is that?

Comment: @frog1944: It seems to be *Artificial Intelligence Illuminated* by Ben Coppin, page 302 ([Google Books link](https://books.google.com/books?id=LcOLqodW28EC&pg=PA302&lpg=PA302)).

Comment: Any book on neural networks will deal with the sigmoid function.   It is useful because of the simple way backpropagation works; a lot of computing work is saved when training a network from a set of results.   In nature, other functions are possible, like arctan, rational functions, and more.

Comment: One of the reasons they use the sigmoid is that it is easy to differentiate and facilitates backpropagation.  Not so for other candidates like sign(x), arctangent(x), sinh(x), etc.

Answer (score 432, accepted):

Let's denote the sigmoid function as $\sigma(x) = \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$.

The derivative of the sigmoid is $\dfrac{d}{dx}\sigma(x) = \sigma(x)(1 - \sigma(x))$.

Here's a detailed derivation:

$$
\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{dx} \sigma(x) &= \dfrac{d}{dx} \left[ \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}} \right] \\
&= \dfrac{d}{dx} \left( 1 + \mathrm{e}^{-x} \right)^{-1} \\
&= -(1 + e^{-x})^{-2}(-e^{-x}) \\
&= \dfrac{e^{-x}}{\left(1 + e^{-x}\right)^2} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}\ } \cdot \dfrac{e^{-x}}{1 + e^{-x}}  \\
&= \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}\ } \cdot \dfrac{(1 + e^{-x}) - 1}{1 + e^{-x}}  \\
&= \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}\ } \cdot \left( \dfrac{1 + e^{-x}}{1 + e^{-x}} - \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}} \right) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}\ } \cdot \left( 1 - \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}} \right) \\
&= \sigma(x) \cdot (1 - \sigma(x))
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Sir, Is d(e^x)=e^x?

Comment: @RavinderPayal: Yes, d/dx(e^x) = e^x; If you want a proof of that see: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/advanced-differentiation-ab/proofs-for-derivatives-of-ex-and-lnx-ab/v/proof-d-dx-e-x-e-x

Comment: Where does the (1 + e^-x) - 1 suddenly come from in third row up from bottom?

Comment: for my untrained eyes this explanation runs rather smoothly except pre-last => last line.  What happens there?

Comment: @Jarad: e^-x == 1 + e^-x - 1; we are just adding 1 and subtracting 1 from the same term, which changes nothing.

Comment: @VladimirIgnatov: Sorry, I'm not sure which line you are referring to.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation is much better than the answer.

Comment: It has been a long time since I've taken differential equations, so Its little complex to understand for me. I understand everything in line 1,2,4-9 except 3. From where there is an extra (-e^-x) ? An explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: @ChoudhuryA.M. The reason why d/dx[(1+e^-x)^-1] = −(1+e^−x)^−2(−e^−x) has to do with the chain rule for derivatives. See https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/dc-chain

Comment: This really help on Andrew's DL week2

Answer (score 122):

Consider
$$
f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sigma(x)} = 1+e^{-x}
.
$$
Then, on the one hand, the chain rule gives
$$
f'(x)
= \frac{d}{dx} \biggl( \frac{1}{\sigma(x)} \biggr)
= -\frac{\sigma'(x)}{\sigma(x)^2}
,
$$
and on the other hand,
$$
f'(x)
= \frac{d}{dx} \bigl( 1+e^{-x} \bigr)
= -e^{-x}
= 1-f(x)
= 1 - \frac{1}{\sigma(x)}
= \frac{\sigma(x)-1}{\sigma(x)}
.
$$
Equate the two expressions, and voilà!

(Cf. also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78560/how-do-you-solve-the-initial-value-probelm-dp-dt-10p1-p-p0-0-1/78576#78576).)

Comment: How do you derive 1 + e^-x as -e^-x? (Update: I think it's because the derivative of e^x = e^x) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rules_for_basic_functions

Comment: @AdamGrant: Yes, since then the chain rule gives $e^{kx}=k e^{kx}$ for any constant $k$. (In this case, we have $k=-1$.)

Comment: Correction to silly typo in the previous comment: it should be $\frac{d}{dx} e^{kx} = k e^{kx}$, of course.

Answer (score 23):

Note that from your given equation,

$(1+e^{-x})\sigma=1$

$\Rightarrow -e^{-x}\sigma+(1+e^{-x})\frac{d\sigma}{dx}=0$ (differentiating using [product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule))

$\Rightarrow \frac{d\sigma}{dx}=\sigma.\frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})}=\sigma.\frac{(1+e^{-x})-1}{(1+e^{-x})}=\sigma.\left[1-\frac{1}{(1+e^{-x})}\right]=\sigma.(1-\sigma)$

Answer (score 9):

Since $\sigma(x)$ is a composite function, firstly we need to use [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) to dig down to the x term, then we can factor back to the $\sigma(x)$
 fuction:
$$ \begin{align} 
\frac{d}{dx}\sigma(x) &= (\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}})' \\
&= -\frac{1}{(1+e^{-x})^{2}} \cdot (1) \cdot -e^{-x}  \\
&= \frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^{2}}, \\
\because \sigma(x) &= \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}, \\
e^{-x} &= \frac{1 - \sigma(x)}{\sigma(x)}, \\
1+e^{-x} &= \frac{1}{\sigma(x)}; \\
\therefore \frac{d}{dx}\sigma(x) &= \frac{\frac{1 - \sigma(x)}{\sigma(x)}}{(\frac{1}{\sigma(x)})^{2}} \\
&= (1 - \sigma(x)) \cdot \sigma(x)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 6):

Let's say we want to find the derivative of $y=σ(x)=(1+\exp(−x))^{−1}$. So we have:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}
& = (-1)(1 + \exp(-x))^{-2} \frac{d}{dx}(1 + \exp(-x)) \\ \\
& = (-1)(1 + \exp(-x))^{-2}(0 + \frac{d}{dx}\exp(-x)) \\ \\
& = (-1)(1 + \exp(-x))^{-2}(\exp(-x)) \frac{d}{dx}(-x) \\ \\
& = (-1)(1 + \exp(-x))^{-2}(\exp(-x))(-1) \\ \\
& = \frac{\exp(-x)}
  {(1 + \exp(-x))^2} \\ \\
& = \frac{1 + \exp(-x) -1}
  {(1 + \exp(-x))^2} \\ \\
& = \frac{1 + \exp(-x)}
  {(1 + \exp(-x))^2}
  -
  \frac{1}
    {(1 + \exp(-x))^2} \\ \\
& = \sigma(x) - (\sigma(x))^2 \\ \\
& = \sigma(x) \cdot (1 - \sigma(x))
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 5):

By directly differenting:

$$ \sigma^{'} (x)= \frac{1. e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2} $$

Separately compute, multiply:

$${\sigma(x)}.{(1-\sigma(x))} =\frac{ e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})  } . \frac{ 1}{(1+e^{-x})  }$$

The RHSs agree.

EDIT1:

In general a solution of differential equation

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=y(1-y) $$

can be seen to be

$$\frac{1}{1+c e^{-x}} \rightarrow \frac{1}{1+ e^{-x}}  $$

with center point integration constant evaluated at $x=0, y=\frac12;\, c=1. $

Answer (score 2):

No answer yet involves the logarithm. If $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm then by the chain rule
$$\frac{d}{dx} \log(\sigma(x)) = \frac{1}{\sigma(x)}\frac{d \sigma(x)}{dx}.
$$
Furthermore $\log(\sigma(x))=\log(e^x) -\log(1+e^x)=x - \log(1+e^x)$ so that
$$\frac{d}{dx} \log(\sigma(x)) = 1 - \frac{e^x}{1+e^x} = 1-\sigma(x).$$
Equaling the two displays gives $(d/dx)\sigma(x) = \sigma(x)(1-\sigma(x))$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using the quotient rule is as follows:

let $\sigma=\frac{1}{1+e^-x}$
upon rearranging ,

$\sigma=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$

using the quotient rule

$\frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {\frac{{f\left( x \right)}}{{g\left( x \right)}}} \right) = \frac{{\frac{d}{{dx}}f\left( x \right)g\left( x \right) - f\left( x \right)\frac{d}{{dx}}g\left( x \right)}}{{g^2 \left( x \right)}}$,

let $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=1+e^x$,

we get
$\frac{d\sigma}{dx}=\frac{(e^x)(1+e^x)-e^xe^x}{(1+e^x)^2}$

upon rearraning, we get :

$\frac{d\sigma}{dx}=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}\frac{(1+e^x)-e^x}{1+e^x}$

upon further rearrangement:

$\frac{d\sigma}{dx}=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}(1-\frac{e^x}{1+e^x})$

$\frac{d\sigma}{dx}=\sigma(1-\sigma)$

Comment: Good work ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

$\exp(-x) = \frac{1}{\sigma} -1 $     (By definition).  Take the derivative of both sides:

$-\exp(-x)= -\frac{\sigma'}{\sigma^2}$

Add the two to get:
$0 = \frac{1}{\sigma} -1 -\frac{\sigma'}{\sigma^2}$

and solve for $\sigma'=\sigma(1-\sigma)$  qed

Answer (score 0):

## Just as a side note

### Known

We know that:

$$ 1 - \sigma(x) = \sigma(-x) $$

From here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

[image: Wikipedia screenshot]

### Further simplify

Therefore this:

$$ \dfrac{d}{dx} \sigma(x) = \sigma(x) \cdot (1 - \sigma(x)) $$

... can be rewritten as:

$$ \dfrac{d}{dx} \sigma(x) = \sigma(x) \cdot \sigma(-x) $$