# why are we ignoring universal constant function in derivative of sigmoid function?

Tags: derivatives

Please take a look at my case:

$$ t(x)=1/(1+exp^{-x})\\therefore\ we\ can\ create\ three\ functions: \\f(x)=exp^{-x}\\g(f(x)) = 1+f(x)\\c(g(f(x)) = 1/g(f(x))\\
$$

we know

$$t'(x) = t(x)*(1-t(x))$$

and i think it should be:

$$t'(x) = t(x)*(1-t(x)*exp^{-x})$$

why?

chain rule says, find derivative of each function and multiply together, therefore we should get out this:

$$
t'(x) = -1(1/g(f(x)))^-2*exp^{-x}*exp^{-x}$$

or on different case:

$$
\\t(x) = ((x^2)^2)^2\\
\\f(x) = x^2\\
\\g(f(x)) = f(x)^2\\
\\c(g(f(x)) = g(f(x))^2\\
$$

therefore derivative is:

$$
t'(x) = 8x^7
$$

Comment: MathJax hints:  if you put backslashes before common functions you get the proper font and spacing, so \exp x gives $\exp x$.  When you want multicharacter exponents, put them in braces, so e^{-x} gives $e^{-x}$ instead of e^-x which gives $e^-x$.  This works everywhere-thinks in braces are considered a unit.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks I fixed it

Comment: Introducing a different $t(x)$ makes your argument hard to follow.  You should start from $t(x)=c(g(f(x)))$ and apply the chain rule to that.  It should also be either $\exp(-x)$ or $e^{-x}$, not $exp^{-x}$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78575/derivative-of-sigmoid-function-sigma-x-frac11e-x

Answer (score 1):

Since $g(y) = 1+y$, we have $g'(y) = 1$ for any $y$, so the middle step of your chain rule is wrong.
It should be $t'(x) = -\frac{1}{g(f(x))^2} \cdot 1 \cdot (-e^{-x})$.

Comment: Thank you. I have read on wikipedia derivative of e{x} is always e{x}. By the way, where this you get - (minuses) in t'(x). I would appreciate it.