# Sigmoid function proof with theta

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, logistic-regression

[Derivative of sigmoid function $\sigma (x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78575/derivative-of-sigmoid-function-sigma-x-frac11e-x)

but:

derive wrt θ1 and not wrt z=∑θixi

show that:
$$
\frac{\partial \sigma(z)}{\partial \theta_1} = \sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z)) \cdot x_1
$$
with:
$$
z = \theta_0 x_0 + \theta_1 x_1
$$

Note that in general (because of symmetry) holds:

$$
z = \theta_0 x_0 + \theta_1 x_1 + \dots
$$

$$
\frac{\partial \sigma(z)}{\partial \theta_j} = \sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z)) \cdot x_j
$$

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using $\sigma(z)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-(\theta_0 x_0 + \theta_1 x_1)}}$
$$
\partial_{\theta_0}\sigma(z) = \frac{e^{-(\theta_0 x_0 + \theta_1 x_1)}\partial_{\theta_0}z}{(1+e^{-(\theta_0 x_0 + \theta_1 x_1)})^2}
= x_1\frac{1}{1+e^{-(\theta_0 x_0 + \theta_1 x_1)}}\frac{e^{-(\theta_0 x_0 + \theta_1 x_1)}}{1+e^{-(\theta_0 x_0 + \theta_1 x_1)}} = x_1\sigma(z)\frac{e^{-(\theta_0 x_0 + \theta_1 x_1)}}{1+e^{-(\theta_0 x_0 + \theta_1 x_1)}}
$$
Now use
$$\frac{e^u}{e^u+1} = \frac{e^u+1-1}{e^u+1} = 1-\frac{1}{e^u+1}$$

Comment: how is it different from: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78575/derivative-of-sigmoid-function-sigma-x-frac11e-x ?

Comment: It's because you derive wrt $\theta_1$ and not wrt $z = \sum \theta_i x_i$

Comment: sorry, I don't get it quiet yet, can you explain a few steps more please?