# solution of differential equation

Tags: integration

I am trying to evaluate integral of the form $dN/(N(k-N))$, where $N(t)$  is function of $t$, I know that without factor of $N$, result will be $\ln(t)$, but what can I  do  with another factor $N(t)$? please help me to solve it

Comment: What is $k$? A function or a constant?

Comment: constant  also one more question if N(t) is a function of t,then integral of N(t) with respect to t    is it equal to (t^2)/2+c?

Comment: It would help to clarify the problem better, but perhaps you are looking for a "partial fractions" expansion: $\frac{1}{N(k-N)}=\frac{a}{N}+\frac{b}{N-k}$ for constants $a,b$ ($a=-b=1/k$ I think).

Comment: So you can use partial fraction: $\frac 1{N(k-N)}=\frac 1k\frac k{N(k-N)}=\frac 1{kN}+\frac 1{k(k-N)}$.

Comment: it is a short  form of logistic equation of population  growth,namely  dN/dt=r*N(k-N)/K

Comment: but how to integrate it?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you know that without the factor of $N$ the result would be $\log t$? If you are saying that $\int{dN\over k-N}=\log t+C$, you are very confused; the correct answer is $-\log(k-N)+C$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78560/how-do-you-solve-the-initial-value-probelm-dp-dt-10p1-p-p0-0-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $${dN\over dt}={rN(k-N)\over K}$$ you get $$\int\,dt=\int{K\;dN\over rN(k-N)}$$ On the left, that's just $t$, and on the right, use Davide's comment to get $$t=\int{K\;dN\over rkN}+\int{K\;dN\over rk(k-N)}={K\over rk}\left(\int{dN\over N}+\int{dN\over k-N}\right)$$ Now, can you do those two integrals?

Answer (score 0):

Use partial fractions:
$$
\frac{1}{N(k-N)} = \frac {1/k}{N} + \frac{1/k}{k-N}.
$$
(And don't forget to apply the chain rule when you find the antiderivative of the second fraction.)

Comment: @DidierPiau : Fixed.

Comment: (It was correct up to a constant.)