# Solution of first-order differential equation $\frac{\mathrm dI}{\mathrm dt}=aNI(t)-aI^2(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you solve the Initial value probelm $dp/dt = 10p(1-p),    p(0)=0.1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78560/how-do-you-solve-the-initial-value-probelm-dp-dt-10p1-p-p0-0-1)

I am reading a proceeding paper where I encountered this differential equation. Can any one kindly write steps of solution (given below) of this equation. 
$$\frac{\mathrm dI}{\mathrm dt}=aNI(t)-aI^2(t)$$
This first order ordinary differential equation has the following general solution:
$$I(t)=\frac N{1+CNe^{-aNt}}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation is separable:
$$\frac{dI}{NI-I^2} = a\,dt.$$
To solve it, integrate both sides.

Comment: thank you. Shall I use partial fractions here.. I am sorry, I am kind of stuck.

Comment: I solved the above equation using partial fractions. I got the same answer I(t) except that there is no 'N' in the denominator... can any one please confirm. Thanks.

Comment: @OsmanKhalid There should be an $N$ in the denominator, i.e. the form given in the question is correct.

Comment: @OsmanKhalid (But if you like, you can include it in the constant, of course: rename $C$ to $CN$.)

Comment: Thank you again for reply. So do you mean we can multiply N with constant C. Is it possible in maths? Actually, I am not getting N in denominator... kind of frustrated. Is it possible to provide some hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you "did" and "mrf". I matched my solution with solution you people referred and got answer of my question.