# Solving a differential equation involving a quadratic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to show that the solution to:
$$
\frac{\partial D}{\partial \tau} =\alpha - \beta D +  \gamma D^2
$$
with terminal condition $$D(u,0)=0$$ and $\beta$ is a function of $u$, 
is 
$$
D(u,\tau)= ~(r_-)\frac{1-e^{-d\tau}}{1-ge^{-d\tau}}
$$
Where $g=\frac{r_-}{r_+}$

So far, I have simplified so that:
$$
\frac{\partial D}{\partial \tau} =\alpha - \beta D +  \gamma D^2 = \gamma(D-r_+)(D-r_-)
$$
Where $$
r_{\pm}=\frac{\beta \pm \sqrt{\beta^2 - 4 \alpha \gamma}}{2 \gamma} = \frac{\beta \pm d}{\sigma^2}
$$
any hints as to how to proceed?

Comment: What is $u$?? Anyway, if you know what the solution should be, why don't you just verify it by substituting it into the equation, instead of trying to solve the equation from scratch?

Comment: forgot to mention that $\beta$ is a function of u. Well I'm trying to learn the method of getting there?

Comment: OK, that's a good reason! Here's a similar example which might be of help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78560/how-do-you-solve-the-initial-value-probelm-dp-dt-10p1-p-p0-0-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems to be about a function $G$ of a single variable $\tau$, such that $G(0)=0$ and solving the differential equation $$G'(\tau)=\gamma(G(\tau)-r_+)(G(\tau)-r_-),$$ for some fixed constants $(\gamma,r_+,r_-)$. The values of $(\gamma,r_+,r_-)$ depend on $u$ but for each $u$, the triplet $(\gamma,r_+,r_-)$ is fixed and $G(\ )=D(u,\ )$ solves such an equation.

To be complete, note that the differential equation above implies that $$G'(\tau)\left(\frac1{G(\tau)-r_+}-\frac1{G(\tau)-r_-}\right)=\gamma(r_+-r_-),$$ hence $$\frac{G(\tau)-r_+}{G(\tau)-r_-}=C\,\mathrm e^{\gamma(r_+-r_-)\tau},$$ for some constant $C$. The initial condition $G(0)=0$ yields $C=r_+/r_-$ and, finally, $$G(\tau)=r_+r_-\frac{1-\mathrm e^{\gamma(r_+-r_-)\tau}}{r_--r_+\mathrm e^{\gamma(r_+-r_-)\tau}}.$$
The parameters $r_+$ and $r_-$ solve the quadratic equation $\gamma r^2-\beta r+\alpha=0$ hence the prefactor is $$r_+r_-=\alpha/\gamma,$$ and the exponent of the exponential is $$\gamma(r_+-r_-)=\sqrt{\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma}.$$ (The square root in the RHS might be your $d$ but then the mysterious $\eta^2$ in your denominator for $r_\pm$ should read $2\gamma$. In any case, a unique exponential function is involved, not two with different exponents, as your answer seems to imply.)

Comment: may I ask how you solved for $G(\tau)$?

Comment: ?? The solution is explained, starting at "To be complete" (and you seem to be retracing the steps of the method explained in my answer, in at least one comment posted since).

Comment: $$\frac{x-a}{x-b}=c\iff x-a=cx-cb\iff (1-c)x=a-cb\iff x=\cdots$$

Comment: Sorry, this was obvious, I think I've been up too long! You're correct about $\eta^2 = 2\gamma$ This is part of a longer proof in a book I'm going through, I wasn't sure how much detail to go into. I've edited the question to add this.

Comment: No problem. (I mentioned the typos because they were possibly misleading.)

Comment: Yes, the exponentials have the same exponent as you mentioned, I've edited that too, thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17495/discussion-between-dimebucker91-and-did).