# Logistic growth of a population

Tags: integration

while studying for my math exam coming up, I stumbled upon this exercise.

A certain product is sold on a market with 1 000 000 potential customers. We assume that the number of people p that have bought the product is growing logistically. So, the function p(t) (where time t is measured in years) satisfies a differential equation of the form
$$\frac{dp}{dt}= \frac{k}{N} p(N - p)$$$, with N the value of p in the long run and k some positive number. It is expected that in three years’ time, a quarter of the potential customers will have acquired the product, that in five years’ time, half of them will and in the long run everybody will.

If I understand correctly we can say that 
p(3) = 1/4 * 1 000 000 ,
p(5) = 1/2 * 1 000 000 , 
N = 1 000 000

The question asked is : 
Find the equation of the function p(t) 
I can't seem to find the right solution
Can somebody enlighten me? 
Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: "putting in these numbers in the equation" has little meaning. What you need to do is to solve the differential equation, and **then** to use the values that are given to you to identify its parameters. (Note additionally that, at present, there is no question in your post.)

Comment: How to solve the ODE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78560/how-do-you-solve-the-initial-value-probelm-dp-dt-10p1-p-p0-0-1

Answer (score 1):

To solve the differential equation, rewrite it as
$$kdt = {dp\over p} + {dp\over{N - p}}.$$
By integrating and re-arranging we get $p = N/(1 + ce^{-kt})$, where $c$ is a constant. The values of $c$ and $k$ can then be found from the information that $p(3) = N/4$ and $p(5) = N/2$.