# Analytic solution for differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, mathematical-modeling

I have the following problem: assuming the growth of a certain population is described by

$\displaystyle{\frac{dN}{dt}=rN(1-\frac{N}{K})-EN}$,

is there a way to find a solution to this differential equation analytically. I am thinking seperation of variables,

$\displaystyle {\int \frac{1}{rN(1-\frac{N}{K})-EN}dN=\int 1 dt}$.

But I am not sure how to evaluate the left integral.

Comment: This has been asked many times before... For example, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78560/how-do-you-solve-the-initial-value-probelm-dp-dt-10p1-p-p0-0-1) and the linked questions there. Anyway, you can also change to $y(t)=1/N(t)$ (to find all nonzero solutions; $N(t)=0$ is trivially a solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply top and bottom by $K$, and factor $N$ out of the denominator.  The denominator is now $N(rK-rN-EK)$ which you can break up with partial fractions.
I pull out $\frac{-K}{r}$ and define $C = K+\frac{EK}{r}$ to get
$$\frac{-K}{r}\cdot \frac{1}{N(N-C)}$$ which you can break up with partial fractions and integrate.  I get $$\frac{A}{N} + \frac{B}{N-C}$$ where $A = \frac{-1}{C}$ and $B = 1 + 1/C$.